# Objective C - Function declaration/definition between precompiled condition

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to write a function between precompiled condition so that, the function will only be available if that condition is true? Also, can I use instance variable there? Like this -

```
#if ([self.object ifVariablenotNil])
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)modalPresentationStyle{
    return UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
}
#endif
```

Comment: yes just add confition

Comment: please show me an example.

Comment: Define "condition". You are using macro, pre-compile conditions...

Comment: @Larme I have edited the question. I thinks it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Yes, but you need if course need to include the condition: `#if condition-expression`

**Longer Answer:**

We're guessing the issue here might be the understanding of what the *condition-expression* may be, if we're wrong ignore the rest!

Directives such as `#if` are part of the (Objective-)C *preprocessor*, they have their own syntax rules quite independent of (Objective-)C. All preprocessing is (at least logically) performed before the (Objective-)C code is analysed and compiled.

What this means is that a preprocessor *expression* cannot use (Objective-)C constants, variables, functions or operators; it can only use preprocessor symbols and operators.

Similarly the (Objective-)C code analysis and compilation has no access to preprocessor symbols *per se* as they have all been textually replaced by the preceding preprocessor phase.

In short: there are two distinct worlds, the preprocessor and the (Objective-)C language, and they do not directly interact.

Preprocessor expressions are, as the documentation puts it, ["subject to stringent restrictions"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If); they only operate on integer and string constants and with a few operators which mirror their (Objective-)C counterparts.

Here is a real example taken from SVGKit:

```
#if SVGKIT_UIKIT && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __IPHONE_7_0
void CGPathAddRoundedRect (CGMutablePathRef path, CGRect rect, CGFloat radiusX, CGFloat radiusY);
#endif
```

Here `SVGKIT_UIKIT`, `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` and `__IPHONE_7_0` are all preprocessor symbols which will either have been `#define`'d elsewhere in the code, given values using a compiler command line switch, come from Xcode's project settings, be defined by the compiler itself, etc..

To evaluate this expression the preprocessor first replaces the symbols by the textual definition (all preprocessor symbols have text values). When compiling for UIKit the above might first be converted to:

```
#if 1 && 60100 < 70000
```

where `1` is the definition of `SVGKIT_UIKIT`, `70000` is the definition of `__IPHONE_7_0`, and `60100` is the definition of `__IPHONE_6_1` and has been chosen as the definition of `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED`.

Having replaced all the symbols the preprocessor values the expression using similar semantics to (Objective-)C, so the lone non-zero `1` evaluates to `true`, `60100 < 70000` evaluates to `true`, and then `true && true` evaluates to `true` and the `if` condition is met so the following *text* (the preprocessor does not care if its (Objective-)C or a poem by Robbie Burns) up to the `#endif` is included in the text passed to the next phase of the compiler.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor expression is a **compile-time** expression not a **runtime** expression.  In other words the compiler must be able to evaluate the expression and therefore you cannot use class instance variables in the expression.

So to answer your question: No, that's not possible.